# ADF Dataflow to replace square brackets [ ] in column headers

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a blobstorage container with csv files and copy them to SQL. In the column headers there are [ ] on every column header.
The [ ] in the headers causes errors on the SQL table side, so we want to replace them with nothing in the pipeline with a dataflow.

If I run the json below as Dataflow I get an error:

Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'sink1': The identifier that starts with 'persoonsnummer |Volgnr dienstverband|Version|Objectid|Pslot_sel|Current niveau autorisatie|Code regeling ORD|Code regeling OVW|C' is too long. Maximum length is 128.

Question: because of too much columns ? Or the first row cant have more then 128 characters
bottomline the question is how to adjust it so it works and why this doesn't .

```
{
    "name": "DF_Beaufort_CSV_to_SQL_copy1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DS_S_Beaufort_YFDienstverbanden",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DS_D_Beaufort_SQL",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "select1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          {[persoonsnummer ]|[Volgnr dienstverband]|[Version]|[Objectid]|[Pslot_sel]|[Current niveau autorisatie]|[Code regeling ORD]|[Code regeling OVW]|[Code regeling AVBAS]|[Code regeling BAW]|[Code regeling SLD]|[Code regeling VBD]|[Code regeling VSD]|[Code regeling ALG]|[Code regeling OVBAS]|[Soort arbeidsrelatie]|[Opdrachtgever]|[Instelling]|[Registratienummer]|[Datum in dienst]|[Organisatorische eenheid]|[Functie]|[Opzegtermijn in mnd]|[Kode normuren]|[Uren per week]|[Percentage deelbetrekking]|[Werkdagen per week]|[Doelgroep]|[Koppelen]|[Datum uit dienst]|[Reden einde dienstverband]|[Soort loner]|[Code salarisregeling]|[Schaal]|[Ancienniteit/functiejaren]|[Inpassingsnummer]|[Extra treden]|[Nominaal salaris]|[Nominaal uurloon]|[Blokkade aanvulling min.loon]|[Blokkade jeugdaftrek]|[Afw. %jeugdaftrek]|[Garantie schaal]|[Ancienniteit]|[Garantie inpasnummer]|[Nominaal garantiesalaris]|[Code deeldiensttijd]|[% Wachtgeld]|[Soort diensttijd ABP]|[Expiratiedatum ABP]|[Garantiesalaris]|[Garantie uurloon]|[Bruto salaris]|[Bruto uurloon]|[Sprongen periodiek]|[Maand periodiek]|[Blokkade periodiek]|[Sprongen periodiek garantiesalaris]|[Maand periodiek garantiesalaris]|[Laatste periodiek]|[Loonheffingskorting]|[Soort loonheffingstabel]|[Procentuele inschaling]|[Code tariefgroep beschikking]|[Soort werknemersverzekering]|[Afwijkende SV-dagen]|[Soort pensioenfonds]|[Datum intreding pensioenfonds]|[Datum uittreding pensioenfonds]|[Reden uittreding pensioenfonds]|[Code verlofregeling]|[Keuze feestdagenset]|[Datum in dienst CAO]|[Ingangsdatum werkpatroon]|[Datum/tijd laatste herberekening salaris ]|[Basissalaris/uurloon ]|[Jeugdkorting ]|[Deeltijd salaris/uurloon ]|[Basis garantiesalaris/uurloon ]|[Jeugdkorting  garantiesalaris/uurloon]|[Aanvulling garantiesalaris / uurloon ]|[Aanvulling minimumloon/uurloon ]|[Basissalaris/uurloon  eerstvolgende period.]|[Basis garantiesalaris/uurloon eerstvolgende period. ]|[Beroep]|[Blokkade ziekteregistratie]|[Ingangsdatum WAO]|[% WAO]|[% WAO uitkering]|[WAO uitkering]|[Ingangsdatum herintreding WAO]|[Ingangsperiode blokkade ziekte salarisverwerker]|[Afw. wachtdagen ZW uitkering]|[Zorgverzekeraar]|[Inschrijfnr.]|[Ing. datum]|[Einddatum]|[Reden]|[Afw. reden]|[Volgnr IKV]|[Volgnr PGGM]|[Percentage Verhoging]|[Code tellen SV-dagen en uren uurloners]|[Aanmaken variabele LV mutaties]|[Blokkeren verdeling TR]|[Verdeelgroep]|[Instellingsnr. hoofddienstvb.]|[Registratienr. hoofddienstvb.]|[FA pakket]|[Status FA]|[Verlofrecht]|[Gewenst aantal vakantiedagen]|[Verlofrecht verkocht]|[Saldo spaarverlof]|[Spaarverlof mutatie]|[Huidige FA versie]|[Perc. deelbetr. F&O]|[Perc. deelbetr. B&B]|[Perc. deelbetr. verlof]|[Reisafstand woon-werk]|[Aantal reisdagen]|[Aantal niet-reisdagen]|[Vergoeding woon-werk]|[ind.blk.fsc.vrije reisk.]|[Percentage Merit-rating]|[Correctie basissalaris]|[Garantietoelage]|[Levensloopverlofkorting]|[Korting uitkering]|[Perc doorbet. langdurig ziek]|[Vrijw voortzetting PGGM]|[Reden uittrede PGGM]|[Soort inkomstenverhouding]|[Aard arbeidsverhouding]|[Invloed verzekeringsplicht]|[Soort contract]|[Code inkomstenvermindering]|[Arbeidsgehandicaptenkorting]|[Ind. loon incl. WAJONG]|[Ind.  personeelslening]|[Afwijk. risicopremie groep]|[Speciale werknemer]|[Jaarloon  bijz. beloning]|[Perc. bijzonder tarief]|[Code blokk. voordeel]|[Loonheffing Blokkering]|[Code bedrijfsauto]|[Code netto loner]|[52% trf loonheffing]|[Vermindering loonh.]|[WIA IVA Uitkering]|[WIA WGA Uitkering]|[Gekoppeld dienstverband indicatie]|[Ind.ber.verlofr.meeruren]} as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source1",
                "source1 select(mapColumn(",
                "          each(match(true()),",
                "               replace(replace($$,'[',''),']','') = $$)",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1",
                "select1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     deletable:false,",
                "     insertable:true,",
                "     updateable:false,",
                "     upsertable:false,",
                "     recreate:true,",
                "     format: 'table',",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     errorHandlingOption: 'stopOnFirstError') ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The above error occurs when the column length is too long and if its more than 128 characters.

You can see I got same error in SQL, when I tried to create a table with a column of length more than 128.

[image]

There is no error in your dataflow transformations. The reason for the above error in dataflow is **your csv file is a Pipe (`|`) separated file**. Due to `,` delimiter in the dataset, it considered all columns as a single column which caused the above error. So, you need to change the Column delimiter in the dataset to `|` from the default delimiter `,`.

[image]

Now, import the schema in the dataset or in the dataflow source projection.

[image]

After importing the new schema, debug the dataflow activity in the pipeline and your columns will be copied as expected like below.

[image]